# SSHD: Dynamic deny port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

From the current ssh session on a server, what `-L` params did the client specify?

I am trying to build a jumphost using sshd that can be used for port forwarding.  The goal is to be able to get into a secure zone and forward the RDP port out so remote desktop can be used.

On my workstation I want to run

```
ssh -NL 1234:my-server:3389 the-jumphost
```

then connect my RDP client to `localhost:1234` (or VNC or $whatever_app).

I want to further lock things down to only allow the port forward to hosts that the user has access to in a separate system. The problem I'm trying to solve is I don't want someone to `ssh -NL 1234:sensitive-server:5900 the-jumphost` then have network access to a service they shouldn't.  To support this, let's say I have a CLI I can run on my jumphost `can_access $user $host`.

At login time (or post login time), how can I tell what the port forwarding options are for an incoming connection.  The closest I've gotten is to put something in PAM

```
auth required pam_exec.so seteuid /is_valid_port_forward
```

But I cannot figure out how to tell what port forwards are being set up.  How can I do this?

### Some additional context:

I have services network isolated from each other so if you log into `my-server`, you cannot talk to `sensitive-server`.  However if you log into the jumphost, you can do anything you want to `sensitive-server`.  The other thing I'm doing is locking down ssh itself with the `can_access` script.

In terms of numbers, I have about 10,000 users logging into ~40,000 hosts on ~1,000 separate networks fronted by 10's of jumphosts behind a DNS load balancer.  Building up `PermitOpen` lists is not feasible hence the need to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

SSH doesn't provide a built-in way to determine the -L (local port forwarding) parameters from within the SSH session itself. However, you can leverage SSHD's logging feature to get this information. By setting **LogLevel VERBOSE** in your **sshd_config** file, SSHD will log port forwarding events.

For example, when a client sets up port forwarding, SSHD logs a message like this:

`debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5901 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:5901`

You can monitor these logs to identify port forwarding activities. However, this is a reactive approach and won't prevent unauthorized port forwarding.

For a proactive approach, consider using the **PermitOpen** option in **sshd_config**. This option lets you specify which host:port pairs clients can forward to. You can set this globally, or on a per-user or per-group basis.

For example:

`'Match User jdoe PermitOpen my-server:3389'`

This configuration allows only user *jdoe* to set up port forwarding to **my-server** on port **3389**. Attempts to forward to other hosts or ports will be denied.

If you need dynamic control over which host:port pairs a user can forward to, you could use a **Match** block with a **ForceCommand** directive to run a script at login. This script could query your **can_access** system to determine the allowed host:port pairs, and then dynamically generate a **PermitOpen** directive for the user's session.

However, this approach is complex and potentially error-prone. It requires custom scripting and thorough testing.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really good response.  I like the idea of the dynamically generated `PermitOpen` but it's going to fall apart for "super" users that have access to all 40k hosts.

You have however clued me onto a potential solution and that's to set an environment variable `SSH_CONNECTION_LOCAL_FORWARDS` in [`channel_setup_local_fwd_listener`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/channels.c#L4086).  That variable can then be used in the PAM script